# What are these catalytic converter bolts called?

Tags: exhaust-manifold

Replacing 2 catalytic converters on my car and one of these bolts broke off. I thought they're called manifold double end studs kit, but apparently they are smaller.

Old bolt thread size is M10 but the Dorman catalog shows M8, so I must not be looking at the right item.

Any idea what these bolts are called?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your best bet is going to be to get rid of the studs, drill out the holes, then replace them with Grade 8 (12.8) bolts with nuts and lock washers. The studs are great for lining things up, but they create an issue when you need to remove the nut after many years of heat and road debris.

Comment: (external) star or Torx bolts. If removing them, soak in penetrating oil and/or heated to break the rust bond. Turn a little in each direction to see if the bond breaks for removal, Rust and corrosion will act like loctite so screw and unscrew to prevent jamming bolt threads with rust. Compare threads by mating removed ones to replacements if you don't have a thread pitch gauge. Sometimes cutting slits into the old bolts can be a poor man's tap to chase rusted threads if you don't want to buy a tap to rethread holes. Once reassembling things, use plenty of anti seize compound made for exhaust

Comment: If you call the main dealer and you describe where they are, they will look them up on their computer.